# How do i know if my alarm manager timer is on?

Tags: android

I'm using this code (from my activity) to start a periodic timer in the application:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),(i * 1000), pendingIntent);
Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm set in " + i + " seconds",
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

I want to know how can i know (from a different activity) is the timer is running?

Answer (score 2):

One possibility I can think of is to check if the pending Intent is defined.

You can call

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
```

this will give you the pending Intent, or null if the Intent was not specified. This will not guarantee that the alarm was set but it is an easy way to check if the set alarm code was called before.

Another possibility is to save all set alarms in a [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) file. In this way you can look for all alarms set by your app in the shared prefs file.

As far as I can see there is no way to get a list of set alarms for your application from the AlarmManager

Comment: Hi, it doesn't work for me, i always get value (not null) from the time i start it.   b.t.w in order to stop the timer i use:    // Prepare the intent
   Intent intent = new Intent(this,
     LocaitonSampleBroadcaseReceiver.class);
   PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
     this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, 0);

   // Stop the timer
   AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
   alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

Comment: This is correct the PendingIntent will be stored until you call cancel on the pending intent. This is the problem with the approach you can only check if the intent exists not if it is registered at the alarmmanager

Answer (score 0):

in stop function

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocaitonSampleBroadcaseReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, 0); 
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE); alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

just add this:

```
pendingIntent.cancel();
```

so you can use the string wrote comment Janusz

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
```